# __call__ behavior

Tags: python, python-3.7

I don't understand the behavior of `__call__`:

```
class Filter:
    def __init__(self, before, after, source):
        self.filter = {}
        self.filter['before:'] = before
        self.filter['after:'] = after
        self.filter['source:'] = source

    def __call__(self):
        return ' AND '.join([key + value for key, value in self.filter.items()])
```

When I call the instance, `__call__` is not executed:

```
print(Filter(before='today', after='yesterday', source='web'))
```

returns `<__main__.Filter object at 0x103f2bf10>`

while

```
print(Filter(before='today', after='yesterday', source='web').__call__())
```

does what I want and returns what is defined in `__call__()`: `before:today AND after:yesterday AND source:web`

Why is this happening? Do I need to create an empty object first, then instantiate it, to make `__call__` work?

Comment: `Filter(before='today', after='yesterday', source='web')` doesn't call the instance, it calls the constructor, `Filter`. Calling the instance would be `Filter(before='today', after='yesterday', source='web')()` although this seems like a very strange use of the `__call__` dunder method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Filter(before='today', after='yesterday', source='web')`, you don't call an instance, you create one. When you `print` it, you get the default representation for an instance of class `Filter`: `<__main__.Filter object at 0x103f2bf10>`

You need to create the instance first, then call it:

```
filter = Filter(before='today', after='yesterday', source='web')
filter()
```

Output:

```
'before:today AND after:yesterday AND source:web'
```

There is no need to explicitely use `<your instance>.__call__()`, just use the parentheses like you would do for any function.

Answer (score 2):

`Filter(...)` does not "call" the instance, it creates it. To call, use the call syntax on the resulting object:

```py
>>> Filter(...)()
```

or

```py
>>> filt = Filter(...)
>>> filt()
```